# App Inventor's aiStarter's: prerequisites to use the USB connection

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, app-inventor

I'm developing an Android application using [App Inventor 2](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/), and I would like to test it live using the USB connection. What are the prerequisites to use the USB connection?

I use Ubuntu 13.04, I installed aiStarter, and apparently aiStarter has trouble to detect my device.

In order for aiStarter to work:

- Should `lsusb` necessarily list my phone?
- Should `adb devices` necessarily list my phone?
- Should libmtp necessarily support my phone?

Comment: http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/setup-device-usb.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the prerequisites listed there. My guess is that  `adb devices` should list my phone, that being listed in `adb devices` implies being listed in `lsusb` and that libmtp is not necessary but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: you might want to ask in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest) instead...

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-are-the-prerequisites-to-use-the-USB-connection-in-App-Inventors-aiStarters